# Are HTTP keywords always in English?

Tags: http

As someone who speaks English, I've never really given this much thought - but recently I've been involved in some international projects involving translations of HTML content.

It occurred to me that - since HTTP is a text protocol, I started wondering - are the verbs (GET, POST, etc.) and other keywords like "Host", "Cookie" always sent in English? (I mean the actual word "Host", not the value of the Host header.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one example that isn't is `Referer`. If it were correct english it would be `Referrer` ;)

But generally the headers and verbs that are standardized are in English. It is however possible for implementors to create their own headers and verbs, and there's nothing stopping them from using non-english words for this.